# Игра "Виселица". Проблема с выводом и заполнения слова

Tags: c++, строки

Помогите дописать программу для игры, где нужно отгадывать слово по букве. Не знаю, как задать алгоритм вычислений буквы слова, выводить всё слово так "*******", кроме отгаданных.

Пример: Ввели букву п, "****п***", ввели букву х, "****п*х*".

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <random>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
struct Game_gallows{
    std::string word_animal[10];
    std::string word_nature[10];
    std::string word_countries[10];
    std::string word_it[10];

};

int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    std::random_device r;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);
    std::default_random_engine random_num(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0, 6);
    char *str;
    int topic_number;
    std::string counter;
    Game_gallows word_a;
        word_a.word_animal[0] = "Корова";
        word_a.word_animal[1] = "Собака";
        word_a.word_animal[2] = "Птах";
        word_a.word_animal[3] = "Черепаха";
        word_a.word_animal[4] = "Ворона";
        word_a.word_animal[5] = "Кит";
        word_a.word_animal[6] = "Риба";
        word_a.word_animal[7] = "Акула";
        word_a.word_animal[8] = "Хом'як";
        word_a.word_animal[9] = "Лелека";
    Game_gallows word_n;
        word_n.word_nature[0] = "Ліс";
        word_n.word_nature[1] = "Поле";
        word_n.word_nature[2] = "Озеро";
        word_n.word_nature[3] = "Дерево";
        word_n.word_nature[4] = "Вода";
        word_n.word_nature[5] = "Поляна";
        word_n.word_nature[6] = "Водопад";
        word_n.word_nature[7] = "Гори";
        word_n.word_nature[8] = "Трава";
        word_n.word_nature[9] = "Море";
    Game_gallows word_c;
        word_c.word_countries[0] = "Америка";
        word_c.word_countries[1] = "Україна";
        word_c.word_countries[2] = "Багами";
        word_c.word_countries[3] = "Вануата";
        word_c.word_countries[4] = "Єгипет";
        word_c.word_countries[5] = "Канада";
        word_c.word_countries[6] = "Лесото";
        word_c.word_countries[7] = "Мадагаскар";
        word_c.word_countries[8] = "Панама";
        word_c.word_countries[9] = "Ямайка";
    Game_gallows word_i;
        word_c.word_it[0] = "Кряк";
        word_c.word_it[1] = "Геймер";
        word_c.word_it[2] = "Розробник";
        word_c.word_it[3] = "Програма";
        word_c.word_it[4] = "Код";
        word_c.word_it[5] = "Баг";
        word_c.word_it[6] = "Репорт";
        word_c.word_it[7] = "Аутсорс";
        word_c.word_it[8] = "Віндовс";
        word_c.word_it[9] = "Глюк";
    std::cout << "Ласкаво просимо в гру 'Шибениця'!" << std::endl << "Правила: " << std::endl <<
            "1) Ви вибараєте тему, в якiй будете вгадувати слова;" << std::endl <<
            "2) Ви вводите номер теми, пiсля чого показується кiлькість букв в словi;" << std::endl <<
            "3) Ви вгадуєте по буквi, набираючи її, букви можуть повторюватися, а якщо нi, то вас про це повiдомлять;" << std::endl <<
            "4) Якщо ви не вгадали букву, то у вас буде ще 5 спроб, щоб вгадати (Однi i тi ж букви, введенi помилково невраховуються;" << std::endl <<
            "Що ж, розпочнемо iгру!" << std::endl << "Виберiть тему:" << std::endl << "1 - Тварини" << std::endl << "2 - Природа" << std::endl <<
            "3 -  Країни" << std::endl << "4 - IТ" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> topic_number;
    std::string random_word;
    std::string s, b;
    char word_letter[10];
    int  l = 0, c = 0;

    switch (topic_number){
        case 1:
            random_word = word_a.word_animal[distribution(random_num)];
            for (int i = 0; i < random_word.length(); i++){ s = "*" + s; }
            std::cout << "Ваше слово: " << s << std::endl;

            for (l; l < random_word.length(); l++){
                std::cout << std::endl << "Введiть букву слова: " << std::endl;
                std::cin >> word_letter[l];
                if (random_word.find(word_letter[l]) != std::string::npos){
                    std::cout << "Букву, яку ви ввели є в словi." << std::endl;

                    std::vector<char> caption_word(random_word.c_str(), random_word.c_str() + random_word.size() + 1);
                    for (int m = 0; caption_word[m] != word_letter[l]; m++){
                        b = "*" + b;
                    }
                    std::cout << b;
                    for (int m = 0; caption_word[m] != word_letter[l]; m++){
                        b = "*" + b;
                    }

                }
                else std::cout << "Букву, яку ви ввели відсутня в слові." << std::endl;
            }

        break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Ваше слово: " << word_n.word_nature[distribution(random_num)];
        break;
        case 3:
            std::cout << "Ваше слово: " << word_c.word_countries[distribution(random_num)];
        break;
        case 4:
            std::cout << "Ваше слово: " << word_i.word_it[distribution(random_num)];
        break;
    }
    _getch();// pause operator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел, где точно у вас вывод, так что вот функция, выводящая слово `word` как вы хотите, если угаданные буквы в строке `guess`:

```
void puts(const string& word, const string& guess) {
    for (char c : word)
        cout << (guess.find(c) == string::npos ? '*' : c);
    }
```

https://ideone.com/bMtPUF